# Visual Studio Team Services build Typescript error

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a angular2 webapplication where I'm using Typescript 2.0. I have install locally in my VS the version 2.0 and changed also the tag for the typescript version in my VS project. Locally vs build works fine. In my CD pipeline on Visual Studio Team Services with a vnext build now build fails with this:

```
2016-11-05T16:10:22.0371090Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe --project "C:\a\1\s\src\Emersy\tsconfig.json"
2016-11-05T16:10:22.7095466Z ##[error]VSTSC(0,0): Error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'strictNullChecks'.
```

Looks like that the build server is using the typesript version 1.8 is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Typescript 2.0 is not available in Hosted Build agent. But you could use Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package instead, after that you could build your project on Hosted Agent with typescript 2.0.

1. Add/Install [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/) to your project
2. Edit your project file (.csproj)

   a.) Configure MSBuild to use the NuGet package's props file.

   ```
   <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.3\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />
   <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />-->
   ```

   b.) Configure MSBuild to use the NuGet package's targets file.

   ```
   <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" />
   <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />-->
   ```

   If it is .Net Core project, add this code to  section of .xproj file

   ```
   <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0.6</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
   <TscToolPath>C:\Users\[user account]\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild\2.0.6\tools\tsc</TscToolPath>
   ```

Comment: do you know when typescript 2 will be aviable in the hosted build?

Comment: @cpiock No, there isn't official article about it. You can track update of this article (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool)

Comment: This answer worked for me, but was initially confusing as I didn't understand the second set of steps were both for editing the .csproj, because the lines are so long you don't see that one sub-step is to use the NuGet package's targets and the other is to use the package's props files. I've submitted an edit to clarify this. I see you use this answer in a lot of places, so hopefully these clarifications can make it easier for others to adopt this fix.

Comment: Note: I just installed the NuGet package (2.0.6) and that's all I needed to do. The package apparently automatically added 2a (2b is not present - works nevertheless)

Comment: If we do this, then do we need still the TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 tools to be installed on every developer workstation?

Comment: @JimBrown TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 tools is used for VS, it includes related items to VS (add item/project)

Comment: It looks like the nuget package version also has to match the TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 version. Otherwise you'll get a compile error.

Comment: Update for 2.6.2: you only need to install the package apparently. The csproj is updated automatically with the targets file. The props file wasn't there in my project and the VSTS build completes successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Hosted build agents have support for TypeScript 2.0 at the moment.

From [VisualStudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software):

```
TypeScript 1.4 for Visual Studio 2013
TypeScript 1.6 for Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015
TypeScript 1.7.5 for Visual Studio 2013
TypeScript 1.7.6 for Visual Studio 2015
TypeScript 1.8.6 for Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015
WIX Toolset 3.10
```

Comment: The documentation seems to be wrong in parts as not all versions listed there worked. E.g. I tried 1.8.6 - not there. 1.4 and 1.6 worked though.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript 2.0.6 is now available to the hosted build agent.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool