# Azure DevOps Hosted Agent uses TypeScript 4.0 compiler but project uses TS1.4

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, msbuild

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps for an ASP.NET MVC project, but this project still depends on TypeScript 1.4.
It looks like the Hosted Agent provided in DevOps only has TypeScript 4.0, and is causing the MSBuild step to fail:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\4.0\tsc.js"...
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\4.0\lib.dom.d.ts(2053,11): Error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'Animation'.
```

Due to time constraints I would rather not try to update the project to use TypeScript 4. Is there a way in which I can configure MSBuild to use TS1.4?

Comment: Can you try to use the [typescript NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler/1.4.0)? You can refer to [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168235/typescript-build-started-failing-over-the-weekend.html).

Comment: I am afraid you have to use the private agent, if you do not want to update the project to use TypeScript 4. That because Typescript 1.4 is not available in Hosted Build agent and the lowest available version of package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild is 1.7.6, check this thread for some more detailshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441320/visual-studio-team-services-build-typescript-error:

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops). When you use self-hosted agents, the pipeline will use your local typescript version. Here are my steps:

1. Install typescript in PowerShell: `npm install -g typescript@1.4.1`
2. Check the typescript version: `tsc -v`

[image]

3. Run pipeline with my self-hosted agent:

[image]